# How to access data in a DataSet within current project?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, dataset

I'm attempting to access a basic table from a local database in my Windows Forms project. I seem to have created the database correctly, and imported the dataset as expected as it displays in my Solution Explorer.

However, I am stuck on how to actually access the data within my database. I've attempted many different solutions but I cannot seem to get anywhere.

Here is what I've accomplished so far:

[Solution Explorer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbXQJ.png)

But I cannot figure out how to make queries to the dataset, whether it's selecting, updating, or deleting rows.

The closest I've come to getting the data is from the code here:

```
    InventoryDatabaseDataSet context = new InventoryDatabaseDataSet();

    var inv = context.Tables["Inventory"];

    var all = inv.Select();
```

But it doesn't return any seemingly valid data.

How do I go about making queries to my dataset? I understand Linq is the common method of making queries, but I don't understand how to get to the point of being able to do such a thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After storing data in DataSet,DataSet is read through DataTable object.
Similarly object of DataRow is used to read the row of a table.
Following is the sample code

```
InventoryDatabaseDataSet ds = new new InventoryDatabaseDataSet();;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM FooTable", connString);
da.Fill(ds, "FooTable");
dt = ds.Tables["FooTable"];

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(dr["Column1"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: No, no, no!  The OP has a typed DataSet so why would you provide code that uses an untyped DataSet?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataSet` item in the Solution Explorer represents a number of types.  Just as `String`, `Int32` and `Form` are types, so `InventoryDatabaseDataSet` is a type.  Just like other types, you create an instance in code and then use it.

You will also find that those types that are components have been added to your Toolbox and can be added to forms in the designer, just like other controls and components.

You can also drag items from the Data Sources window and have the designer generate appropriate objects and code.  For instance, if you drag a table from the Data Sources window to a form, it will generate a `DataSet` to store the data, a table adapter to retrieve data from the database and save changes back,  a `DataGridView` to display the data, a `BindingSource` to link between the `DataTable` and the `DataGridView` and a `BindingNavigator` to navigate the data.

If you do use the designer then you'll see code generated to retrieve data by calling `Fill` on the table adapter and save changes by calling `Update`.  If you want to do it in code yourself then you can do it something like this to retrieve:

```
var data = new InventoryDatabaseDataSet();

using (var adapter = new InventoryTableAdapter())
{
    adapter.Fill(data);
}

this.InventoryBindingSource.DataSource = data.Inventory;
this.InventoryDataGridView.DataSource = this.InventoryBindingSource;
```

and this to save:

```
this.InventoryBindingSource.EndEdit();

var data = (InventoryDataTable) this.InventoryBindingSource.DataSource;

using adapter = new InventoryTableAdapter())
{
    adapter.Update(data);
}
```